# Scraping JSON value from HTML body

Tags: javascript

```
var pageInfo =  {
  "applicationId":"OLB",
  "marketSegment":"CLASSIC",
}
```

I have the above content in HTML body. I want to scrape applicationId's value.
How can I do this using JavaScript? Is there any other option to substr method?

Comment: Give proper example to understand.

Comment: Do you mean text? so first find this object in RegExp, and parse from string to JSON, and get value.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get this by doing simple json operation.

Try this `pageInfo.applicationId`